# Cannot find MinGW .a files in opencv folder

Tags: windows, opencv, mingw, codeblocks

I am trying to get OpenCV working with Code::Blocks and MinGW on Windows but whenever I download and install an OpenCV installer, I only find three folders in the newly created directory C:\opencv\build\x86, which are vc10, vc11 and vc12. There is no mingw folder and the vc10, vc11 and vc12 folders contain .lib files in their lib folders (whereas I'm supposed to find the .a files).

I already downloaded three versions of the OpenCV installer. I tried a lot to find a post about the same problem on Google but a version without a mingw folder isn't mentioned anywhere, so before I download the fourth I would like to know if I'm doing something wrong other than downloading a wrong version. If not, what is the latest version that contains a mingw folder and where can I find it?

Comment: you're out of luck with mingw. there are no prebuild opencv libs any more. you will have to compile the libs from src using cmake. and no, getting a previous version won't help you either. (the mingw world is just too fragmented, libc++ and such)

Comment: May be its too late to reply. If you are still searching for MinGw in Opencv, if you have got some old projects based on mingw in Opencv. use this unofficial [link](http://www.filewatcher.com/m/OpenCV-2.4.5.exe.278901549-0.html), here I used second link to download opencv-2.4.5. But I don't know if this does holds good for new projects.